# How can I enable X11-Forwarding (ssh -X) support in remmina for ssh?

Tags: ssh, xorg, remmina, x11-forwarding

I can connect to a remote server with ssh in remmina. When I try to open a X applicaton like lxterminal, I get following error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(lxterminal:4458): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:44:57.015: cannot open display:
```

Using ssh on the terminal with X11-Forwarding (`ssh -X` or `ForwardX11 yes` in `ssh_config`) I can open X-applications on the remote server.

I did not find any option to enable X11-Forward support in remmina. Does remmina provide this feature?

I am using remmina 1.4.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Remmina displays some already running X server (or Wayland, I suppose, but not sure of Remmina's support for Wayland) on your system. SSH forwards your X server to some other system, so that applications on your system can draw on your X server. The two have nothing to do with each other. Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: when I connect with remmina with ssh to the remote-server, it open a new window with a remote temrinal. When I type 'lxterminal', I get this error. I want to use remmina as ssh-management-tool for my remote-servers

Comment: ## [v1.2.32.1](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/tags/v1.2.32.1) (2018-11-14)

* Removing X11Forwarding code as it is wrong and causing issues (Antenore Gatta)